# Angular ng-repeat over directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a simple directive

```
directive('animalCard',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<div>time for {{a}}</div>'
    }
});
```

that I want to iterate over an array

```
$scope.animals = ['penguins','cows','turtles'];
```

with HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="a in animals">
    <animal-card>{{a}}</animal-card>
</div>
```

inside the curly braces for the template  I'm using `a` as the expression to iterate over, and in this case it makes enough sense to say a in animals.  But what if I wanted to use this same directive when iterating over something where the variable `a` wouldn't make sense?  Is there a better solution to this other than using some generic interpolatable expression like `{{item}}`?

Comment: Why would you use this directive for other things? It's called animalCard.

Comment: perhaps this was a poor example to demonstrate what I'm actually curious about.  It seems not quite as reusable as it could be given that if I wanted to iterate over a set of animals I always have to use the variable `a` (since it's in the HTML of the template.  I suppose it doesn't really matter, just seems like it could be dynamic, maybe.

Comment: You should pass dependencies through directive attributes, and use the directive's scope config to specify how it binds it's data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your question is more '*What should I call my loop variable?*`In the end it really doesn't matter. As long as you (or others looking at your code) understand what it's doing it's fine.

If you want it to be more semantically readable, then you will need to change the name to something generic:`item`,`data`,`str`,`d`(for data),`i`(as i is often used for iterations/loops.

Comment: If OP is iterating over 'animals' why wouldn't a single item in that list be an 'animal'? Why would you want to use a generic name like 'item'?

Comment: I wouldn't use something like that. But from reading his question, I got the impression (from reading the last 2 sentences of post) that he isn't asking a question about how to do something, but rather what should he name a variable.

Comment: It is all just developer preference in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You directive is literally incorrect. First of all, to insert something into directive from outside, you need `transclude: true`. Second, you must bind your variable `a` in `ng-repeat="a in animals"` to scope of directive, so it can understand what you want.
So working directive should look like

```
directive('animalCard',function(){
return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope:{
         a: '@'
    },
    template: '<div><div>time for {{a}}</div><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    }
});
```

And the last thing.

```
<div ng-repeat="a in animals">
    <animal-card a="{{a}}">this content will be placed at the end, because of ng-tranclude attr in directive</animal-card>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wuZvc9GAUNMV0922FPIL?p=preview)

**Edit**
oh, i glanced at code and seems misunderstood point of question. But naming convention really shouldn't make sense, i usually use `item`. But if you want to reuse it for very different object models, you probably should use different directive with additional decoration. And yes, it will be not reusability at this point. But for same object models, it's reusable, and you shouldn't meet any problems with naming, as they are same type. imo